# storage().ref().putString() limitations?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase 3.4.1 javascript API and trying to persist several string content into storage engine.

The first ones are successfully persisted, but quickly, I get lots of errors :

```
{"code":"storage/retry-limit-exceeded","message":"Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again.","serverResponse":null,"name":"FirebaseError"}
```

Is there any storage limitation on allowed writes per second ? Tried to browse the website/FAQ but didn't see any of this anywhere.

Note : I recently migrated to Blaze account, but it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Which browser is this in? That error isn't for rate-limiting, it indicates there was a problem communicating with the server (which can also be caused by browser-specific bugs or unsupported browsers).

Comment: I'm having the same issue trying to .put() a byte array from a React Native app